# Task Factory Method with Delay

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to call a particular method with 5 mins delay:

```
try
{
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
       HttpContext.Current = ctx;
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
       Sendafter5mins(param1,params2);
    });
}
catch (Exception EX)
{
    //Log Exception if any  
}
```

This method is failing silently sometimes without any exception in log.

Please Suggest me is this the right way to fire a method with 5 mins delay.

Comment: What does "failing silently" mean? Do you see any exceptions?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't run a task 5 minutes after a web request and expect the original context to be still valid - at this point the response was sent and the context and all other related objects disposed. Running background tasks in a web application [is not trivial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't await the Task, nor Wait() on it, any exception thrown from `Sendafter5mins(..)` will **not** get caught in your `catch` block. If you are not using .NET 4.5, this should fail the whole process since the exception will fail the finalizer thread. Change your code to:

```
try
{
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContext.Current = ctx;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
            Sendafter5mins(param1,params2);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Log Exception if any
        }

    });
}
catch (Exception EX)
{
    //This will catch unlikely exceptions thrown from HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current 
    //  or the creation of the Task
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If by "failing silently" you mean there's an exception and you don't catch it that's because you are starting a new task without waiting for the result. Your try-catch can't catch the exception as it's stored inside the task and isn't rethrown.

Anyways, if all you want is a delay use `Task.Delay` with async-await instead of creating a new Task and blocking its thread:

```
async Task SendAfterDelay()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        Sendafter5mins(param1,params2);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```